# Matrix determinant where $a_{ij} = i + j$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, laplace-expansion

So I'm studying for my course of linear algebra and the following problem was inside the book with exercises. "Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, where $a_{ij} = i + j$, calculate it's determinant".

The first thing I did was make a small visualization of what this sort of matrix would look like. I came up with this:

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 + 1 & 1 + 2 & ... & 1 + n\\
2 + 1 & 2 + 2 & ... & 2 + n\\
... & ... & & ...\\
n + 1 & n + 2 & ... & n + n
\end{pmatrix}$$

I set of to set up an expression for the determinant using cofactor expansion (I don't know if this is the correct English terminology for it, the formula is given below, I also found on wikipedia this is called "Laplace Expansion"?) to the first row (thus making $j = 1$ in the expression):

$$ \sum^{n}_{i = 1}(-1)^{(i + 1)}a_{i1}det(M_{i1})$$

where $det(M_{i1})$ is the minor for the $i1$-th element. This is the point where I am stuck and could definitely use some help. I've tried writing $A$ in terms of summations to maybe see something in it, but this evolved into some very complex expression which I'm not even going to bother typing down (it's really, really long).

I have a feeling that I can bring the $a_{i1}$ out of the summation but I'm not sure how I would go on doing that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume "derivative" should instead be "determinant"?

Comment: All columns differ only by a multiple of the $(1,1,1,\cdots,1)^T$ vector, so can this matrix have full rank ?

Comment: Also, how does one find the determinant of a matrix whose columns and rows are not equal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix with entries $a_{ij}=i+j $ . Calculate rank of $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2283993/let-a-be-a-n-times-n-matrix-with-entries-a-ij-ij-calculate-rank-of). The rank is $2$, so $\det(A)=0$ for $n>2$.

Comment: @user170231 yes I've made the edit, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3282904/42969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determinant is undefined if $m\neq n$, so consider matrices $A^{n\times n}$ with $a_{i,j}=i+j$.

For $n\ge3$, the determinant is $0$. The second row can be written as a linear combination of the first and third rows:

$$\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}2&3&4&\cdots&1+n\end{bmatrix}^\top+\begin{bmatrix}4&5&6&\cdots&3+n\end{bmatrix}^\top&=\begin{bmatrix}6&8&10&\cdots&4+2n\end{bmatrix}^\top\\[1ex]
&=2\begin{bmatrix}3&4&5&\cdots&2+n\end{bmatrix}^\top
\end{align}$$

The cases of $n<3$ are trivial (but non-zero!).

Comment: So just because this is a linear combination, which means (using Gauss elimination) you can reduce the matrix to contain a 0-row which will make the determinant 0?

Comment: Yes. Look at your definition of Laplace expansion and calculate the determinant using that row...

Comment: I see now, thanks for the insight!